# Pyglet image.TextureGrid error when given an ImageGrid

Tags: textures, pyglet, skybox

I am attempting to draw a Skybox with TextureGrid from an existing file with the following code:

```py
boxname = 'skybox1.jpg'   
print('Loading',boxname)
skygrid = image.load(os.path.join('Assets', boxname))
sky_grid = image.ImageGrid(skygrid, 3,4)
sky = image.TextureGrid(sky_grid) # as per the documentation
sky_frames = [sky[4], sky[6], sky[9], sky[1], sky[7], sky[5]]
```

Traceback of the error I get:

```
Loaded skybox1.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyglet\resource.py", line 435, in file
    location = self._index[name]
KeyError: <TextureRegion 64x64>
```

`TextureImage` is erroneously trying to use `resource` to read the `TextureRegion` as if it were a file. I'm on Python 36. I've upgraded to latest Pyglet but no change. I've looked at the Pyglet image, gl, and resource code but am none the wiser.

Comment: How do you know it is trying to load `TextureRegion` as if it were a file?

Comment: because  resource is doing 'location = '  and is cocerned with reading files.  Whatever the reason, the TextureGrid code does not behave as documented.

Comment: Tbh never used the `TextureGrid` but it feels like you should do `pyglet.image.ImageGrid(os.path.join('Assets', boxname)) `, could you give it a go? Also the full stack trace would be nice in this case because I'm not sure if it's the `ImageGrid` or the `TextureGrid` that gets messed up :)

Answer (score 0):

Loading the Imagegrid first was fine.   It turns out that the imagegrid contents were what was needed to build cube image textures so I don't need to use texturegrid at all.
Still slightly disturbing that a documented feature fails to work.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my problem:

```
skygrid = image.load('Assets/skybox/' + boxname)
print('Loaded',boxname,'Format wxh',skygrid.format,(skygrid.width,skygrid.height))
skyg = image.ImageGrid(skygrid,3,4) # pyglet reverses y axis so swap top,btm
sky  = image.TextureGrid(skyg)   # extract 6 face textures in that order
skyFace = [sky[4], sky[6], sky[9], sky[1], sky[7], sky[5]]  # image data
```

So I can now display cubmaps from grid format.